# Cannot find changelog because no version code given - please specify :version_code

Tags: circleci, fastlane

I am using Fastlane with circle CI to upload build to google play store.

Everything works fine till fastlane version 2.134 after that apk is getting uploaded but 
it Circle CI fails with "Cannot find changelog because no version code given - please specify :version_code" error message.

Below is my supply for fastlane.

```
supply(
        track: 'production',
        package_name: options[:package_name],
        skip_upload_metadata: true,
        skip_upload_images: true,
        skip_upload_screenshots: true
    )`
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Dec 1 you need to use at least v2.135, because that version adopted Google Developer API v3 (and Google dropped support for v1 and 2).

Comment: I added version_code in the supply.

supply(
track: 'production',
package_name: "com.xxxxx.xxxxx",
skip_upload_metadata: true,
skip_upload_images: true,
skip_upload_changelogs: true,
version_code: 119,
version_name: "1.0.1-20191218-4",
apk: "/home/circleci/code/app/build/outputs/apk/awcc/release/app-xxxxx-release.apk"
)

But still, I m getting the same error.